# Android: How to override navigation drawer toolbar menu in a Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I'm creating an application with a navigation drawer and I need to edit his toolbar where I'm in a specific fragment.

I've tried to inflate it by overriding the 'onCreateOptionsMenu' function in my fragment class:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_main, menu)
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
}
```

I expect to have "menu_activity_main" menu overridden on the action bar menu but it's not.

It currently looks like this: https://prnt.sc/p32sj5

But I want this menu instead: https://prnt.sc/p32tp4

Comment: EDIT: You're supposed to call `setHasOptionMenu(true)` if you're using a Fragment. (Please ignore my previous comment)

Comment: P.S. Please use Imgur instead of posting links to external sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because you didn't call the [`setHasOptionMenu(Boolean)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu(boolean)) method in your Fragment class (as what the notes of the [`onCreateOptionsMenu`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu,%20android.view.MenuInflater)) method specify you're supposed to).

This should be placed ideally in your `onCreate` lifecycle hook:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setHasOptionMenu(true)
    // ...
}
```